# SwiftyJSON Issue

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire, swifty-json

I'm using Alamofire to get data from an API. I'm using SwiftyJSON to parse the JSON response. Currently, I'm iterating through product data and want to extract product details and display them in a collection view. The issue is, I can't seem to figure out how to access each product in the array. Here's the array that's returned:

```
{
                  "1": {
                    "product_id": 2982493187,
                    "merged_status": "TRUE",
                    "merged": [
                      {
                        "id": 2982493187,
                        "title": "Waves Eclipse Tee in Black",
                        "handle": "waves-eclipse-tee-in-black",
                        "published_at": "2015-10-09T21:00:50-07:00",
                        "published_scope": "global",
                      }
                    ]
                  }
                },
                {
                  "2": {
                    "product_id": 2982432131,
                    "merged_status": "TRUE",
                    "merged": [
                      {
                        "id": 2982432131,
                        "title": "Waves Eclipse Tee in Off White",
                        "handle": "waves-eclipse-tee-in-off-white",
                        "published_at": "2015-10-09T21:00:50-07:00",
                        "published_scope": "global",
                      }
                    ]
                  }
                }
```

For each of these products I want to access the product_id. I'm trying to do so like so: productArray[0]["produdct_id"].int, but it doesn't seem to work. Any ideas?

Comment: the context of your problem indicated that your top level, productArray, should be accessed as a dictionary, not array

Comment: How do I go about doing that?

Comment: The above is not valid json, if that it what is being parsed.

Answer (score 0):

You do not have an array in your results, but a dictionary with keys of "1", "2", etc.

```
let product_id = result["1"]["product_id"].int
```

Comment: The json you have above in not valid json. You can view the details by plugging it in to [JSONLint](http://jsonlint.com/).

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the result json is an array of dictionary, so you can access the product_id via

```
let product_id = result[0]["1"]["product_id"].int
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
let jsonProductsArray = JSON(theRawJSONData).array

for (key, productJSON):(String, JSON) in jsonProductsArray {
    print(key);
    let product_id = productJSON["product_id"].int
    print(product_id)
}
```